# "default constructor cannot be referenced" in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015

I am facing a really weird error message in Visual Studio 2015. The following stripped down code:

```
struct A
{
    A(int val = 0)
    :
        x(val)
    {}

    int x = 0;
};

struct B: A
{
    static int y;
};

int B::y = 1;

struct C: B
{

};

int main()
{
    C c;
    return 0;
}
```

compiles without any problem on Clang. However Visual Studio 2015 IntelliSense gives the following error message:

```
the default constructor of "C" cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function
```

Am I missing something in my code, or this is a bug in Visual Studio?

---

**UPDATE**

Based on the comments and answers here I have opened a [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2070261) on Microsoft Connect.

Comment: It compiles though, right? I wouldn't worry about IntelliSense errors. It gets confused sometimes and mistakenly reports problems.

Comment: It's a bug in (Intellisense in) Visual Studio. All Visual Studio bugs are true. AFAIK. Intellisense doesn't use the same analysis machinery as the compiler. That may change in the future, though.

Comment: I feel like we see a few of Intellisense bugs a week on SO.

Comment: It almost feels like we need a canonical question for this but not sure how to structure it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an Intellisense bug. Both clang and gcc accept this code, also [webcompiler an online Visual c++ compiler accepts this code](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/).

The draft C++14 standard section `12.1` *[class.ctor]* says a defaulted default constructor for a class is deleted if:

> - X is a union-like class that has a variant member with a non-trivial default constructor,
> - any non-static data member with no brace-or-equal-initializer is of reference type,
> - any non-variant non-static data member of const-qualified type (or array thereof) with no brace-orequal- initializer does not have a
>     user-provided default constructor,
> - X is a union and all of its variant members are of const-qualified type (or array thereof),
> - X is a non-union class and all members of any anonymous union member are of const-qualified type (or array thereof),
> - any potentially constructed subobject, except for a non-static data member with a brace-or-equalinitializer, has class type M (or array
>     thereof) and either M has no default constructor or overload
>     resolution (13.3) as applied to M’s default constructor results in an
>     ambiguity or in a function that is deleted or inaccessible from the
>     defaulted default constructor, or
> - any potentially constructed subobject has a type with a destructor that is deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted default
>     constructor.

none of which applies here.

**Update**

In the [bug report filed by the OP](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2070261) the response was:

> Thank you for reporting this issue. Fix should be available in the next update to Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Do you know whether `cl` (the actual C++ compiler used by Visual Studio) accepts the code?  That's somewhat more relevant to a VS user than gcc and clang.

Comment: @BenVoigt [webcompiler accepts the code](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) unfortunately I can't make a live link. I wish they would add it, all the rest of them let you make live links and it a useful feature.

Comment: Couldn't figure out why Visual Studio was upset, but I was declaring private data members as Const.  Moving the Const fields to global scope resolved the issue

Comment: yes removing the const from variables in class somehow solves this issue

Comment: In some cases, if a class member is a reference like fstream& file, we can see this error, all  reference types should be initialized at the construction level.