# inheriting from an interface with no constructor inheriting from a class with protected constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

Although I suspect the answer here is to refactor, I'd like to avoid that due to time constraints.

What I have is a class C, that publicly inherits from interface A, that publicly inherits from interface B, that publicly inherits from class O.

O has a protected constructor.
A and B don't have a constructor (or at least I'm not defining one.  Are they inherited? deleted?)
C has a public constructor.  Calling said constructor results in a compile error:

> 'B::B(void)': attempting to reference a deleted function

```
class C : public A {
public:
C(){};
~C(){};
}

C::C() {
this->property = value;
}

class O {
public:
virtual ~O(){};
protected:
O(){};
}

class B : public O {
public:
virtual ~B(){};
}

class A : public B {
public:
virtual ~A(){};
}
```

using visual studio 2015.

Again, if possible would like to avoid a major refactor. Is there quick(ish) solution?

Edit: When calling C's constructor, it's in the form of
    O* object  = new C();

Comment: "that publicly inherits from interface A, that publicly inherits from interface A" - uh, what? A inherits from itself?

Comment: C is trying to invoke B's default constructor which is apparently deleted (Can't tell without you showing us.) If there is a way to instantiate B, you best do it explicitly in the constructor for C.

Comment: Perhaps this is relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733360/why-do-we-not-have-a-virtual-constructor-in-c

Comment: @user2357112 whoops, inherits from A that inherits from B.  fixed now.

Comment: @DeiDei I haven't explicitly written constructors for A or B, but I haven't deleted them either.  would they inherit from O?  Would they get default c'tors?

Comment: @jakerman999 Can you show us what A and particularly B look like?

Comment: You should create a mcve that exhibits the issue

Comment: So, where is `property` defined?

Comment: After fixing the grammar issues, cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: **−1** This is **not the real code**. Only people with strong ESP capability can farsee the details of the real code. Voted to close as lacking reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this to be related to ["default constructor cannot be referenced" in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33978185/default-constructor-cannot-be-referenced-in-visual-studio-2015)

Work around found by giving the interfaces protected constructors.  Not ideal but works, thank you all.